# clogged kitchen sink, is it the garbage disposal?

Tags: kitchens, drain, garbage-disposal, clog

Some how a bag of carrots got put down the garbage disposal and now the sink wont drain...

Garbage disposal appears to work, like the motor sounds healthy and the blades appear to spin fine... I took apart the P trap after the garbage disposal and all the connections to the garbage disposal where looking inside of it I could not see anything visually wrong with the device or a clog.

Any ideas to try?

Comment: Did you try a sink plunger?

Comment: actually yes... its just a small tiny plunger we have (like a mini version of a normal sized one) and even with the garbage disposal running with the sink filled up when plunging it will just squirt water every where.... It gets a good suction but it seems like something is really clogged.

Comment: definitely a clog in the garbage disposal right? And not something down stream of it...?

Comment: i even tried shoving some ice inside the garbage disposal and running it to see if it would break something loose but my ice maker was only giving me small chunks and not very good ice cubes

Comment: *I took apart the P trap after the garbage disposal* What happens if you try to pour a bunch of water down the trap after the disposal? If that works OK then the problem is the disposal. If that doesn't work then the problem is farther down. (Reminds me of the chicken soup event...that one was past the disposal)

Comment: With the trap off, consider putting a bucket under the disposal and pouring some water through the disposal to see if it comes through okay (do not run the disposal. They emit a large amount of pressure.) Likely the plastic is wadded up further down the pipe and you may want to snake it to pull the debris back rather than driving them further into the drainage system.